# Select the five highest distinct records

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm running MySQL server. In my database I have a table for logging page requests:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `log` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userId` smallint(5) NOT NULL,
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `page` varchar(127) NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

I want to fetch a list of logs, such that only the last five records of any user visiting a certain page are shown. For example, if some user has visited some page seven times, only the last five records are shown. Apart from that, the query should return all records.

I came up with the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `log` 
WHERE `time` > 
  (SELECT `time` FROM `log` as l 
  WHERE `l`.`userId`=`log`.`userId` AND `l`.`page`=`log`.`page` 
  ORDER BY `time` DESC LIMIT 5,1)
ORDER BY `time` DESC
```

The subquery should select the fifth record. This works fine. However, when a user hasn't visited a certain page more than five times, nothing is returned, because the subquery can't find a result (I think). How can I make it work also for that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I just learned something.  MySQL does not permit `limit` in subqueries with `in`, which I thought extended to other similar operations (see the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subquery-restrictions.html)).   But, apparently this works.

Note:  neither of the following work.

This version might work:

```
WHERE `time` > (SELECT MIN(`time`)
                FROM (SELECT time
                      FROM `log` l 
                      WHERE `l`.`userId` = `log`.`userId` AND `l`.`page` = `log`.`page` 
                      ORDER BY `time` DESC
                      LIMIT 5
                     ) l
               )
```

You might also try this formulation:

```
WHERE `time` > ANY (SELECT time
                    FROM `log` l 
                    WHERE `l`.`userId` = `log`.`userId` AND `l`.`page` = `log`.`page` 
                    ORDER BY `time` DESC
                    LIMIT 5
                   )
```

I'm not sure if the restriction on `LIMIT` in subqueries applies to the `ANY` keyword.

EDIT:

Neither of the above works because of limitations in MySQL.  The following should work assuming there are not too many matches:

```
WHERE `time` > (SELECT TIME(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(time ORDER BY time DESC), ',', 5), ',' -1))
                FROM `log` l 
                WHERE `l`.`userId` = `log`.`userId` AND `l`.`page` = `log`.`page` 
               )
```

This uses the `group_concat()`/`substring_index()` trick.  I don't like the solution, but it should technically work, unless you have so many matches within a group that you exceed the length limitation for `group_concat()` (which can always be set to a higher value).  I do wonder if there is a better way, though, using just a `where` clause.

As a note:  the most efficient way to do this sort of this is often to use variables to enumerate the rows.

Comment: Thanks very much. I tried the first option, but MySQL complains about the  deepest subquery not having an alias. After adding an alias, it complains still: `Unknown column 'log.adminId' in 'where clause'`. The second option says `This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery`.

Comment: @CamilStaps . . . I was worried about those two problems.  If I think of anything else, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Is joining on the derived query also out of the question? Seems like the first answer would work if the syntax were correct.

Comment: @MarcusAdams . . . There are other solutions.  I'm wondering if there is a way to do this in the `where` clause.  Or at least a better way than I'm about to propose.

Comment: This third option works nicely, wonderful, thanks. (I had to change the `TIME()` cast to `TIMESTAMP()`, otherwise it returned everything again). The table keeps track only of the last so long time and afterwards the log is stored in a file elsewhere, where no simple user has access to it and no fancy queries are required - so there probably won't be the issue of the length limitation. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
LIMIT 5,1
```

means:

skip 5 records, then take 1

Therefore, no results will be returned if there is less than 6 records.

Comment: I understand _why_ it doesn't work, I mentioned it even in the question. But how can I make it work if there are no 6 records? That's the question.